# get one file name that has *.nupkg extension from given folder in to a variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm a rookie in windows batch programming. The following is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal
set sourcedir=C:\Projects\Libraries
set pdbdir=C:\Projects\App\bin\Debug\net461
set dlldir=C:\Users\radiraju\.nuget\packages

@echo Cleaning up the solution. Please wait...

FOR /d %%F IN (%sourcedir%\*) DO (del /q /s %%F\bin\debug\ 1>nul)

@echo Cleaning up completed. Rebuild Started.

FOR /f %%F IN ('dir /ad /b %sourcedir%\*') DO (

    if not "%%F"==".vs" (
        cd %sourcedir%\%%F
        dotnet pack
        xcopy %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\net461\%%F.pdb %pdbdir% /Y
        del /q %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\*.symbols.nupkg 1>nul
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir /b /a-d %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug') DO (
        set _ver=%%I)
        xcopy %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\net461\%%F.dll %dlldir%\%%F\%_ver%\lib\net461 /Y
    )
)
```

In last statement I get `%_var%` as empty. Not sure why.

Comment: before last statement set _var=%_var:.nupkg=% & set _var=%_var:%%F.=% should be added to find the version number and that version will be used in last statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir /b /a-d %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug') DO (
    set _ver=%%I)
```

will set `_ver` (not `_var`) to the last filename found in the directory. **Caution: The default order for a NTFS volume is NAME order. Order in FAT volumes is not defined**

```
    xcopy %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\net461\%%F.dll %dlldir%\%%F\%_ver%\lib\net461 /Y
```

You appear to want to use the value of `_ver` set in the previous logical statement. Please read about **Delayed expansion**. The value of any `%var%` in a block is replaced by that variable's value when the block is first parsed, not with the run-time value of the variable.

To use the run-time value of the variable, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` AND then use `!var!` in place of `%var%` OR you could invoke the commands in a separate subroutine OR you can use a dynamic flag:

```
    del /q %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\*.symbols.nupkg 1>nul
    set "flag=Y"
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir /b /a-d /O-N %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug') DO if defined flag (
     set "flag="
     xcopy %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\net461\%%F.dll %dlldir%\%%F\%%I\lib\net461 /Y
    )
```

Note here: `flag` is set to some value (any value, so long as it's set) then the `FOR %%I` is invoked with the `dir` list in reverse-name order `(/O-N)` so that the required element appears first (/O-D will yield reverse-date order if that's more suitable). When the first element is returned by the `FOR %%I` then `flag` is cleared and the `xcopy` invoked using the *version?* in `%%I`. Since `flag` is cleared, then the `if defined` will prevent the `xcopy` on further directory entries. (`if defined` operates on the run-time value of the variable)

Note also that you can modify an `if` with the `/i` switch to make it case-insensitive if need be.

Comment: Than you for the suggestion. Following worked for me.

Comment: in my case the foler %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\ will only have one file with extension ".nupkg" (eg. LibraryName.1.1.0.nupkg)

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir /b /a-d %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\\*.nupkg') DO (set _ver=%%I)
 set _ver=!_ver:.nupkg=!
 set _ver=!_ver:LibraryName.=!
 xcopy %sourcedir%\%%F\bin\debug\net461\%%F.dll %dlldir%\%%F\!_ver!\lib\net461 /Y